# How to use navigationController.pushViewController in TableCell class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Using `UITableviewcell` class for displaying the cell of table list. I want to redirect from one screen to another using "`navigationController?.pushViewController`", but it is not supporting in table cell class. So how can i move `UIViewcontroller` using pushViewController from table cell.

My code is:

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell
{
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SubMain", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailReport") as! DetailReport
    nextViewController.aryOfResultList = aryForCreateJSONResult
    cell.inputViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)

}
```

But its not working. Please give me the solution of my question

Comment: Do you want to perform navigationController?.pushViewController when a table view cell is tapped?

Comment: yes i want to perform navigationController?.pushViewController when a table view cell is tapped

Comment: Add navigationController?.pushViewController in didSelectRowAt indexPath method

Comment: yes in didSelectRowAt indexPath method

Comment: Just add your push code in didselect  method

Comment: @BhavishaKhatri Don't use navigationController.pushViewController in TableCell class. Use this in didSelectRowAt indexPath method

Comment: @BhavishaKhatri please check my answer

Answer (score 5):

Declare a variable in the cell called `var parent: UIViewController?`. 
in the parent controller, in the function `cellForRow`,

```
cell.parent = self
```

now in the cell you can call

```
parent?.navigationController.pushViewController
```

**Update**
if what u want is simply to push the view controller when a cell is taped, u can do it in the parent controller in:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always navigate using the navigation controller from one view controller to another and table view cell is not a `UIViewController` type, its a `UIView` type.

You can either create a delegate in custom table view cell and that will confirm the `UIViewController` and implement the cell delegate's method in view controller.

or you can navigate to other screen then cell is tapped in table view.

Comment: Please share the code so i will get better idea

Comment: @BhavishaKhatri no ios developer doesn't know `didSelectRowAt` your question is miss understood that you need a navigation from a specific action inside the cell , Do you still find it impossible to see duplicates and read other answers here with `didSelectRowAt`

Answer (score 0):

Get the ViewController from helper function :

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

and then in your custom cell, use `parentViewController.navigationController`

You can use this for all `UIView` types.

Answer (score 0):

You've to assign `pushViewController` code into `tableView didSelectRowAt()` method
e.g.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
 {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SubMain", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailReport") as! DetailReport
    navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
 }
```